# How to comment out multiple lines in gradle.properties file in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In android studio to comment out multiple lines in .kt file or .java file we use shortcut

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>/</kbd>

But the same key combination doesn't work for commenting out multiple lines in `gradle.properties` file

Is there any other shortcut for this?

This is my `gradle.properties` file

```
## For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Sun Jun 14 20:23:34 IST 2020
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx2048M"
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Select all the lines you want to comment out and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to comment out all the lines

Comment: I guess you forgot to mark it as the answer boy.